# Why did the images increase in size after importing them into Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures

I have a large set of jpg images with a total size of 10 mb, but when I import them into unity, their size increases several times! How do I keep the original size of the images?

Answer (score 3):

**Above answers are wrong, thus, I decided to explain it further here.**

Be careful, size for disk is different from size in ram/gpu.
The one you found in import settings is the size on ram. The default one(without mip) should be the smallest size(almost) for app size.

Although it shows bigger size in import settings, your app will still compressed them again for the build app, and app installer.

**Why the size in ram is so huge?**
In graphic rendering, all the images(no matter jpg or png) will be read and decode. The decoded result will be all pixels array..etc, depending on your texture format(after decode), you will have different size in ram.
However, your source image is usually the highly compressed(encoded) image for disk storage. That's why you get a bigger size after importing to Unity. It counts on how many pixels in total.

You can still keep the original size, only if you keep it as separate resource and load it in runtime. as external resource in resource folder etc. However, it won't reduce the memory usage in RAM or GPU.

Any images which you imported to the project, will be resampled and encoded by their format. The size you see in import settings, which is also the size for ram.

JPEG or PNG is just a format for disk storage. The size you seen inside unity is the size in Ram for rendering. The larger the size, the more ram it needs too.

If you are looking for smaller app size, Unity's default compression will be the best(without mipmap). When you export as apk for example, it will recompress all the assets anyway.

Of course you can still keep the original image as external source and load it in runtime, but your overall app size with external source will be much huge, according to my experience.

As external image in resource folder won't be compressed together with the app assets.

Comment: that said, you should be aware that disabling mipmaps might lead to more aliasing artifacts if the texture is shown at different distances.

Comment: Depends on the texture purpose, if it's a tile in different distance, you should keep the mipmap on.
If it's a 4k or 8k texture for one 3D object(not tiles), then disable the mipmap.

Comment: In general, I will disable all mipmap by default. Only add mipmap when it's flickering in far distance or you found issue on important 3D objects.

Answer (score 0):

you can click at image in unity ,the image has a propertie call `Pixel per unit`
you can adjust it to control size of image